# Disable swagger in django projectt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have set up drf-yasg swagger and now I'm wondering what's the best way to disable swagger, because they should not be exposed after going live.

Comment: Remove the drf-yasg view from your urls.py?

Comment: I set the public to False in drf-yasg view and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*I keep forgetting how to do this so I'll just leave it here for future reference.*

I've been using [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg#a-get-schema-view-parameters) and the basic example uses "Allow All", but it has an extra parameter to restrict permissions to the docs.

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view


schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="My API",
        default_version="1.0",
        description="Some API description",
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAdminUser] # <- change who can access here
)
```

List of valid permissions from Django Rest Framework:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#api-reference